# How to pass array for a POST request in HTTPBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, httpbuilder

The post request code that I use:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(uri)
http.request(Method.POST, ContentType.TEXT){
    send ContentType.URLENC, attrs

    ..Response handler code...         
}
```

here attrs is a map with the key&value that needs to be passed such as:

```
[param1:'value1', param2:'value2', param3:'value3]
```

I need to support passing multiple values for the same parameter, hence passing as a map is not an option. What is my alternative in this case? What I need to pass:

```
[param1:'value1', param1:'value2', param3:'value3']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
send URLENC, [param1:['value1','value2'], param3:'value3']
```

Your example won't work as a map can't have multiple keys with the same name